# How to add a logo or icon for erc20 crypto token?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan, polygon, ethereumj

I am planning to launch my own crypto tokens on polygon. But couldn’t understand the process properly of how to upload logo for the token.  Also I don't think on testnet I can test it.
Is there any easy way to set up your token logo before listing. Please help.

Comment: That has nothing to do with ethereum and the blockchain. Wallet providers and exchanges and are those who set and show icon to their coins

Comment: So how do I ask them to show my icon?

Answer (score 3):

ERC20 tokens have optional metadata of name, symbol and decimals (for details see: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20 558).

Token icons and any other metadata are not part of the specification. Each application/dapp may have a different way of setting this information.

For adding an icon to Etherscan, please see their guide:

https://info.etherscan.com/token-update-guide/

Note you will need to verify contract address ownership first:

https://info.etherscan.com/how-to-verify-address-ownership/